# Implementing access to vector of stucts using a vector as indices

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

Some higher-level languages have this feature, and I'm attempting to implement in C++. I'm not sure if there's a library that already does this somewhere, but if there is, it would save me a lot of trouble. Anyway, here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Let's say I have a vector of structs that have a double and an int as members, and that I have another vector of ints that represents the indices of the elements in the vector of structs that I want to keep.

```
typedef struct
{
double x;
int y;
}s;

std::vector<s> v;
std::vector<int> inds;
```

Is there a way to implement accessing the elements in the structure using the vector of indices in a manner similar to this, or has it been implemented elsewhere?

```
std::vector<double> dResult = v[inds].x;
std::vector<int> iResult = v[inds].y;
```

It would also be nice to be able to access all of the elements in this manner:

```
std::vector<double> d = v.x;
```

Are these things possible?

Comment: You want to construct those two vectors, `iResult` and `dResult`? Do you want to retain `v` and `inds` afterward? If so, are you worried about the two sets of vectors diverging later?

Comment: Please do not use typedef struct in C++

Comment: v should be retained, I likely don't care what happens to inds.  dResult and iResult should always contain a subset of v's members and will probably not be modified. However, I may look for the maximum or minimum of dResult and iResult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You cannot use that syntax with existing definitions of `std::vector`.
2. You cannot create a global operator overload function that provides that syntax since `operator[]()` can be overloaded only as a member function.
3. You can create a non-member function that provides the functionality but without using that syntax.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::vector<T2> getElements(std::vector<T1> const& vec,
                            std::vector<int> const& indices,
                            T2 (T1::*member))
{
   std::vector<T2> ret;
   for ( auto index : indices )
   {
      ret.push_back(vec[index].*member);
   }
   return ret;
}
```

and then use it as:

```
std::vector<s> v;
std::vector<int> inds;
std::vector<double> dResult = getElements(v, inds, &s::x);
```

Answer (score 3):

No such built-in functionality exists, and I'm not aware of any existing library solutions either. But it's not too difficult to write a couple of function templates that do this for you.

```
template<typename Container, typename T, typename M>
std::vector<M> select_mem(Container const& c, M T::* mem)
{
    std::vector<M> result;
    result.reserve(c.size());

    std::transform(c.begin(), c.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
                   std::mem_fn(mem));
    return result;
}
```

The above template takes a reference to a container and a pointer to a data member. It then copies that data member from each element in the input container into the output `vector`.

```
template<typename Container, typename Indices, typename T, typename M>
std::vector<M> select_mem(Container const& c, Indices const& ind, M T::* mem)
{
    std::vector<M> result;
    result.reserve(ind.size());

    std::transform(ind.begin(), ind.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
                   [&c, mem](typename Indices::value_type const& i) {
                       return std::mem_fn(mem)(c[i]);
                   });
    return result;
}
```

This is an extension of the previous template that also accepts a container of indices, and only copies the data members at the indicated indices within the input container.

Use them as follows:

```
std::vector<s> v {{10, 1}, {20, 2}, {30, 3}, {40, 4}};

for(auto const& x : select_mem(v, &s::x)) {
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';

std::vector<int> indices{1,2};
for(auto const& x : select_mem(v, indices, &s::x)) {
    std::cout << x << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e57471310ede1355)

Comment: +1, although since you are at it… using a lambda for the mapping of the original type to the destination would make this a more flexible algorithm, and taking the input ranges as iterators would further extend the usability...

Comment: @David I started out writing it with iterators as arguments, but that makes the second overload a bit messier to write. Not sure what you mean by *using a lambda for the mapping ...*. Are you saying replace `mem_fn` with a lambda? If so, how does that make it better?

Comment: @David Okay, I think I understand what you meant. You're saying it would be better to replace the pointer to data member with an arbitrary callable that you call with each element. Agreed, that does make the function more flexible, but it also makes `select_mem` a misnomer :) It should probably be called `map`, or something similar, in that case.

Comment: Yes, in Dietmar Kühl's terms, provide a *generic* property mapping, have the call look like `select(v, std::mem_fn(&s::x))` so that a different user can do `select(v, [](auto x){...})` with some operation that might not be just calling a *member* function

Answer (score 0):

To get syntax close to what you desired you could create a class that wraps a vector of your structs and has member functions for each of the member variables in your struct:

```
class VecS {
  const std::vector<s>&   v;
  const std::vector<int>* inds;

  template<typename R>
  std::vector<R> impl(R s::* pm) const {
    if (inds) {
      std::vector<R> ret(inds->size());
      auto get_at_index = [this, pm](int index){ return v[index].*pm; };
      std::transform(inds->begin(), inds->end(), ret.begin(), get_at_index);
      return ret;
    }
    std::vector<R> ret(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), ret.begin(), std::mem_fn(pm));
    return ret;    
  }

public:
  VecS(const std::vector<s>& v) : v(v), inds(nullptr) {}
  VecS(const std::vector<s>& v, const std::vector<int>& inds) : v(v), inds(&inds) {}

  std::vector<double> x() const { return impl(&s::x); }
  std::vector<int>    y() const { return impl(&s::y); }
};
```

If you are willing to abuse `operator[]` you can go one step further and add something like:

```
VecS operator[](const std::vector<int>& inds) { return VecS(v, inds); }
```

And then you can write:

```
auto vs = VecS(v);
auto dResult = vs[inds].x(); 
auto iResult = vs[inds].y();
```

and of course:

```
auto d = vs.x();
```

[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bM0MGJ5p0KfyEiXm).