# What is "Class::*"

Tags: c++

I am learning SFINAE(Substitution failure is not)
I found an example of it in a site,

```
template<typename T>
class is_class {
   typedef char yes[1];
   typedef char no [2];
   template<typename C> static yes& test(int C::*); // What is C::*?
   template<typename C> static no&  test(...);
   public:
   static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

I found a new signature, `int C::*` at a line 5. At first I thought it is `operator*` but I suppose it is not true.
Please tell me what is it.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member

Comment: I am sorry asking a similar question. I tried to search it by keyword "::*" but I could not find it. And thank you for letting me know the link to the similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int C::*` is a pointer to a member of class `C` whose type is `int`.

Example:

```
struct C
{
   C () : a(0), b(0) {}
   int a;
   int b;
};

int main()
{
   int C::*member1 = &C::a;
   int C::*member2 = &C::b;
   C c1;
   c1.*member1 = 10;  // Sets the value of c1.a to 10
   c1.*member2 = 20;  // Sets the value of c1.b to 20
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, R Sahu. It was new for me. Please let me ask you more. Is it a special keyword like "this" keyword? Does it exists anytime even when the class does not have member? Thank you very much again.

Comment: The type exists even if a class does not have a member but you can't initialize it to point to a member. For example, you can use `float C::*member3 = nullptr;`. Since `C` does not have a member of type `float`, `member3` cannot point to a member of `C`.

Comment: @mora Its not a keyword, its language syntax, its a mechanic that allows you to specify a pointer to a member of a class. What makes it special is that it is not a pointer to a member of a specific object, but a pointer that is good to the same member of any objects of that same class. I honestly cant think of any practical use for this mechanic, but the language offers it if needed.

Comment: @Havenard, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987112/implementing-access-to-vector-of-stucts-using-a-vector-as-indices/30987413#30987413) for an example usage of this language construct.

Comment: @RSahu Thats a nice example.

Comment: Thank you very much R Sahu and Havenard.